# MacOS sometimes switches to a different app without a reason

Tags: macos, mac, osx-spaces

I have a problem with **macOS agressively switching to another app** from the one I am currently in. It happens **two or three times a day** when I am writing text, suddenly it kicks me off the current app in the middle of a word, and it moves me to another Space (so I continue writing in the window that has been newly focused).

It kicked me off like this from Chrome and Firefox, both in fullscreen. It has never happened with a window on a Space (no-fullscreen app). The apps I am transported to vary; it has been another Chrome profile, Whatsapp Chrome app (attached in Dock), another time I ended up in Photos, all running on my first main Space (so that's where I land every time).

It switches to an app that is currently running (it does not open a new app). As I was writing simple text and it happened literally in the middle of a word, I don't know about any possible shortcut that could have been pressed.

I have Macbook Pro 2019, **macOS Catalina 10.15.6**.

**Question**: Has anyone tips on how to debug this? Any tool that can log something in the background I could check afterward it happens?

Comment: My hunch is you're bumping your touchbar when reaching for number/symbol keys. Or maybe it's a trackpad "palm rejection" problem. Consider changing the settings for your touchbar and trackpad. Also check System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control (the one you have to toggle open) and see how you have those shortcuts set.

Comment: I'm looking at an app called Contexts, that adds a bunch of shortcuts and quick gestures for switching apps. Any chance you have that installed and its screwing you up? I also saw on a forum post about cursor jumping that some people have an issue where the Mac battery begins to swell, and pushes up against the bottom of the keyboard and trackpad, creating "ghost" clicks and presses. Can you try to reproduce the issue on demand with certain words or a particular letter that you type? Just a few quick suggestions to look at.

Comment: @Spiff I use an app called Pock that shows running apps on the touchbar, but I feel like I don't reach all the way up when typing. Anyway, I will try to kill this app to eliminate that. I have tried switching Spaces with trackpad while typing and it does not focus a window, which is what happens to me. Thanks!

Comment: What has changed , loaded or when did this start?  Sounds like low Ram like I get on IOS 13 with latest updates,.  Accelerated planned obsolescence?  use a backup?

Comment: @JimDiroffII I don't have this app, but I will try to kill some apps I installed recently and see. I have mostly the same apps that I had on my old Air, where this did not occur, as I recovered it all from a backup. I was writing just simple text, I have not noticed any link between the words. I will try to note down the keystroke I pressed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Spiff** in the comments was correct.

> My hunch is you're bumping your touchbar when reaching for
> number/symbol keys.

As I reach for some symbol keys (in fact, the keys from 1, 2, 3… to 0 have some letters of my native language), I actually touch the touchbar with my free middle finger. As I mentioned I used an app called *Pock* to show Dock on my touchbar, and I was clicking on the running apps.

I tried to change the position of controls on my touchbar, moved Dock, brought brightness control instead, and after some time, while writing, I accidentally adjusted my brightness level. So, I knew that was it. Thanks for the comment, Spiff!

What was weird, I used the *HapticKey* app for touchbar and even that sensation didn't make me realize I had touched it (because I didn't notice the haptic reponse). Now I've installed *My TouchBar My rules* and will try to move some buttons and adjust the layout to fit my needs.